# Trying to cat the result of piped commands

Tags: sorting, pipe, cat

I have a folder of files that are named list20140801.txt list20140802.txt ....

I'm trying to do this

```
ls | sort | tail -3 | cat
```

But it is just giving me the file names, not cat'ing them.

Answer (score 3):

According to the `cat` manual, cat's job is to:

> Concatenate FILE(s), or standard input, to standard output.

There is no reason why `cat` should treat its standard input as filenames. What you need is

> ls | sort | tail -3 | xargs cat

instead.

Check `xargs` man page for more information: http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_xargs.htm

Comment: as per @garyjohn's answer above, the ``sort`` is redundant in this simple case.

Answer (score 0):

The output of `ls` is already sorted by default in the same manner as `sort` sorts by default, so `sort` is not needed.

The most common way to pass a generated list of files to a command is to use `xargs`. See the `xargs` man page for details, but in this case you don't need any options.  (`xargs` may not do what you want if you have a huge number of files, but in most common cases it works fine without you having to think about that.)

The version of `tail` used on many Linux systems these days does not accept just `-3` as an option. It requires that you use `-n3`.

Finally, the `cat` at the end of your pipeline is not doing anything useful, so it can be omitted, too.

This command should do what you want.

```
ls | xargs tail -n3
```

**Update**

I just read @AtomicHeartFather's answer and realized that I may have put the `tail` with the wrong part of the problem. In that case, the command would be

```
ls | tail -n3 | xargs cat
```

which is pretty much what AtomicHeartFather wrote except for the `sort`.